# Symfony do not insert new value, instend recive already existing id in database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, mariadb

made tracking table in my DB where I am saving which urls was visited at which  time.

```
const INSERT_TRACKING_SQL = "
    INSERT INTO `custom_tracking` (
      `utidId`, `url`, `urlParams`, `time`
    ) 
    VALUES 
      (
        :utidId, :url, :urlParams, now()
      );
  ";

$conn = $entityManager->getConnection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare(self::INSERT_TRACKING_SQL);
$stmt->bindParam(':utidId', $utid_db_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':url', $url);
$stmt->bindParam(':urlParams', $urlParams);
$stmt->execute();

$tracking_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

But after executing the SQL command and getting ID of new record trough **lastInsertId()** I got last record witch have same parameters (except time) and any new record is not inserted into DB

Answer (score 0):

I am using Sulu framework, when this framework is caching http request in the way, when then it does not access controller that is rendering the page.

This can be problem in symfony application when the controller is cached. There are 2 solutions to this problem

1. Disable caching for this controller
2. In my situation, use JS ajax request that will save log about user page access.